# If usbfs has been deprecated, then why is /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbfs directory present?

Tags: usb

This [blog](http://dcjtech.info/topic/usbdev-usbfs-subfs-and-others/), as well as several other StackOverflow posts, say that `usbfs` has been deprecated since Ubuntu 9.10. If that is the case, what is `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbfs` doing there?

Comment: On another note, people sometimes forget to follow through on deprecation. My favorite example: `bash` supports a syntax for arithmetic expressions `$[...]` that is essentially equivalent to the standard `$((...))`. If you dig through the Git repository for `bash` (which dates back to 1996), you find no mention of the syntax in the man page, and a note in the `NEWS` file regarding `bash` 2.0 at the time saying that `$[...]` is no longer supported. Yet support remains in `bash` 5.0, released 14 months ago.

Answer (score 17):

The deprecated `usbfs` refers to a pseudo-filesystem which was typically mounted under `/proc/bus/usb` and was completely removed from the kernel with the 3.5 release.

However the functionality provided by the old `usbfs` filesystem is still present, *via* `sysfs` and [the “`usbfs` driver”](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.10/source/drivers/usb/core/devio.c).

So what was deprecated was the separate filesystem; the functionality survives in a different location, and isn’t deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

Probably because it hasn't been removed. "Deprecated" [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) that you are discouraged from using the technology, and there is a plan to eventually remove it some time in the future. It does not mean the technology has already been taken away.

Some products will deprecate a feature in one release, and remove it in the following one. In some cases a lot of people continue to use the deprecated feature and so it stays on to give them time to transition to a different way of doing things.